# Recursively find combinations of three numbers that sum up to given number

Tags: java, recursion

Given a number between 1 and 30, find all three-number combinations that sum up to this number and return the amount of combinations without using loops.
for example, given 5, print

```
1 + 1 + 3 
1 + 2 + 2 
1 + 3 + 1 
2 + 1 + 2 
2 + 2 + 1 
3 + 1 + 1
```

This is what I have right now, using Java.

```
private static int numbers(int num, int num1, int num2, int num3){
    boolean valid_solution = num1+num2+num3 == num;
    int counter = 0;
    if (valid_solution){
      System.out.println(num1+" + "+num2+" + "+num3);
      counter++;
    }
    if (num1>10 || num2>10 || num3>10 || num1+num2+num3>num){
      return counter;
    }
    counter += numbers(num, num1 + 1, num2, num3)+numbers(num, num1, num2 + 1, num3)+numbers(num, num1, num2, num3 + 1);
    return counter;
  }

  public static int solutions(int num){
    if (num < 0 || num > 30) return 0;
    return numbers(num, 1, 1, 1);
  }
```

I seem to get duplicates, for example for 5-

```
3 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 1
2 + 1 + 2
2 + 2 + 1
1 + 3 + 1
1 + 2 + 2
2 + 1 + 2
1 + 2 + 2
1 + 1 + 3
```

edit - I'm also not allowed to use global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see why the duplicates are happening if you add a little logging

```
1:1:1
2:1:1
3:1:1
3 + 1 + 1
4:1:1
3:2:1
3:1:2
2:2:1
2 + 2 + 1
3:2:1
2:3:1
2:2:2
2:1:2
2 + 1 + 2
3:1:2
2:2:2
2:1:3
1:2:1
2:2:1
2 + 2 + 1
3:2:1
2:3:1
2:2:2
1:3:1
1 + 3 + 1
2:3:1
1:4:1
1:3:2
1:2:2
1 + 2 + 2
2:2:2
1:3:2
1:2:3
1:1:2
2:1:2
2 + 1 + 2
3:1:2
2:2:2
2:1:3
1:2:2
1 + 2 + 2
2:2:2
1:3:2
1:2:3
1:1:3
1 + 1 + 3
2:1:3
1:2:3
1:1:4
counter:9
```

so since you are making recursive calls on incrementing numbers, when you're recursively calling num2+1, you want to make sure that num1 is less than or equal to num2 in order to avoid duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicions that this code of mine is far from being a good solution, but who knows, may be it will be helpful for you in some way.

```
public class FindSumCombinations {

static int start = 5;
static int comb1 = 0;
static int comb2 = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    comb1(start);
}
public static int comb1(int x){
    if(x == 0) return 0;
    comb1 = x;
    comb2(x);
    return comb1(x-1);
}

public static int comb2(int x){
    if(x == 0) return 0;
    comb2 = x;
    comb3(x);
    return comb2(x-1);
}

public static int comb3(int x){
    if(x == 0) return 0;
    if(x + comb2 + comb1 == start){
        System.out.println(comb1 + "+" + comb2 + "+" + x);
        System.out.println(x + "+" + comb1 + "+" + comb2);
        System.out.println(comb2 + "+" + x + "+" + comb1);
    }
    return comb3(x-1);
}
```

}

Comment: Cant use static variables, unfortunately.